# How to display Variables in C++

Tags: c++, c

I've been recently programming on C and I want to know how can I do this:

```
printf("Hello %s" &username);
```

in C++

```
cout << "Hello %s" &username;
```

doesn't work. I'm still new so be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be:

```
cout << "Hello " << username;
```

The address doesn't need to be passed as you would be attempting to print a pointer. You can also chain calls by doing `cout << x1 << x2` which is equivalent to `(cout << x1) << x2`. This works because the result of the first call returns the stream so you use the operator function again.

The chained calls are the same as:

```
cout << "Hello ";
cout << username;
```

Comment: @Yariz - it is polite that if you think somebody has posted an answer that satisfies your question that you click the "check mark" below the number on the left - this tells everyone that you are happy and nobody else needs to work on a solution for you

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I tried, but it said something like wait 7 minutes, I got bored and went to script.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use printf in C++, although you have to do it correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char username[] = "Slartibartfast";
    printf("User: %s\n", username);
    return 0;
}
```

However the correct "C++ way" to do it is to use an `iostream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string username = "Slartibartfast";
    std::cout << "User: " << username << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

C++ streams work primarily with the `<<` (write to) and `>>` (read from) operators, but they also have their own member-functions for doing more complex things and there are some helper functions for things like reading a whole line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter a username:\n";
    std::string username;
    std::cin >> username;
    if (username.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Empty username was input. Aborting\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Welcome, " << username << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Tell me what else you'd like this program to do?\n";
    std::string feedback;
    std::getline(cin, feedback);
    std::cout << "Thank you, you typed " << feedback.size() << " characters of input which I will now ignore.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Some explanations:

`std` is a namespace into which most of the C++ standard functions/routines are placed. This helps avoid clashes with user defined functions/objects/variables.

`::` means 'belonging to', read from right to left, `std::cin` means `cin belonging to std`.

`cin` equivalent to `stdin`

`cout` equivalent to `stdout`

`cerr` equivalent to `stderr`

`endl` a special object that writes a "\n" and forces the output buffer to be flushed.

`std::getline` lets you read from an `iostream` to a `std::string`

`<<` is a short-cut for a function called `operator<<` which takes an iostream and a thing, and returns the iostream, so you can daisy chain it:

```
std::cout << "Hello, " << 42 << " days since last " << adjective << " accident\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<"Hello "<<username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of function overloading, you don't need to specify how `cout` should interpret what you pass it. Basically, there is a version of `operator<<` overloaded for most of the basic types (`int`, `string`, `char`, and so on). Hence you can simply write

```
cout << "Hello " << username;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Hello " << username << endl;
```